# create CLLocationCoordinate2D from array

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I have a plist with dictionary of array's with coordinates (stored as strings).

I want to create a CLLocationCoordinate2D from every array and crate an overlay for the map.

I did that -

```
NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]  pathForResource:@"Roots" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *pointsDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];

 NSArray *pointsArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[pointsDic objectForKey:@"roade1"]];

 CLLocationCoordinate2D pointsToUse[256];

 for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
  CGPoint p = CGPointFromString([pointsArray objectAtIndex:i]);
  pointsToUse[i] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(p.x,p.y);
  NSLog(@"coord %f",pointsToUse [i].longitude);
  NSLog(@"coord %f",pointsToUse [i].latitude);

 }

 MKPolyline *myPolyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:pointsToUse count:256];

 [[self mv] addOverlay:myPolyline];
```

but the app is crashing without any error.
(BTW when i remove the addOverLay method the app does not crash).

I have 2 questions-

1. What am i doing wrong?
2. I have tried to set the pointsArray count as the argument for the CLLocationCoordinate2D like that -

   CLLocationCoordinate2D pointsToUse[pointsArray count];

And i am getting an error.
How can i set the CLLocationCoordinate2D dynamically ?

Thanks for any help.
Shani

Comment: iOS apps never crash without some sort of error. Did you receive a "SIGABRT" or "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"?

Comment: Could you post the output from the Console?

Comment: you are right, i recived an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error.

Comment: Run your app again. When you receive the error, go to the Run menu, and click Debugger. On the left side, are there any calls that are black and not gray? If so, list them.

Comment: Evan - what does it mean if the calls are black or if they're gray?

Comment: @Dan K. If they appear gray on the list, they are system function calls, and cannot be debugged. If they appear black, they are function calls made directly by the application that is being debugged.

Comment: Can you post your viewForOverlay method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O.K
The problem was indeed in the viewForOverlay method (thanks  aBitObvious and all the rest).
It appears that the line loading of the point from the array is working good.

and for the second question i just separated it to 2 steps:

```
  NSInteger c = [pointsArray count];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D pointsToUse[c];
```

and it worked fine, so if any one is looking for a way to load overlayes from plist, that way is working for me.

Thanks 
shani